# Отключение эмуляции запросов php 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

при выставлении атрибуту **PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES** значения FALSE, возникает ошибка:

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in*

На локальной машине и VPS-хостинге (LAMP Ubuntu), на веб-хостинге атрибут принимает значение false

Также при запросе ошибок:

*Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'time.dp.date_start' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in*

Запрос:

```
select dp.*,msp.sale 
from discount_products dp inner join ms_products msp on msp.ms_id=dp.product_ms_id 
where dp.date_end >= :date group by dp.product_ms_id order by dp.date_start
```

более того, это не единственный запрос, возвращающий fatal error

Comment: Значит с выключенной эмуляцией ваш запрос становится некорректен для СУБД. Покажите запрос, на prepare которого получаете false.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу